# Pytorch print what happens (temporary matrices) within imported Model

Tags: python, debugging, import, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to better understand a model that I import (model.py) and train in main.py. The model only returns the loss which I optimize but I'd like to look at different elements within the model. Print statements placed within the model.py file don't seem to work when running main.py. What can I do?

Comment: `print(model)` gives you its architecture, do you want something else?

Comment: Yeah, my model contains some matrix multiplications and I would like to inspect some of the shapes of the matrices to better understand what is happening. But as model only returns the loss, I cannot acces these temporary objects. And print() statements in the imported modul don't seem to print.

Comment: Check out `torchsummary` package or my `torchlayers-nightly` package build, they provide shapes after each layer in Keras like fashion.

Comment: for `torchlayers` it would be `pip install -U torchlayers-nightly` and than `print(torchlayers.summary(model, *args, **kwargs))` where `args` and `kwargs` are example inputs to your model.

Comment: Thanks for your response, will try!